# Smooth Curve Fit

Tags: r, curve-fitting, smoothing, trigonometry

I uses supsmu to fit a smooth curve to a scatter plot of data [image: here].

I am quite new to curve fitting, but my graph looks somewhat sinusoidal. What would you recommend in terms of next steps to determine a predictive model for this patterns. I have tried this simple code:

```
xc<-cos(2*pi*trend$x/104)
xs<-sin(2*pi*trend$x/104)
fit.lm <- lm(trend$y~xc+xs)
```

Any other opinions on methods?

Comment: Use the pink line itself as a table of predictions?

Comment: @Alexis I did. I am asking about any other regression methods?

Comment: Are you familiar with Fourier transforms? If not, you might want to read up on them. since this is a time series, you also might want to try a time series model.

Comment: @kurtosis is it much different from what I have tried in the code I showed?